# Can you deduct state income with a non-sponsored 529?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 529-plan, michigan

I live in MI and it has a state sponsored 529 program called [MESP](https://www.misaves.com/plan/?&tc_mcid=se_Branded_MESP_MESP&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI6PqRlJWi_AIVQfvICh3AxAzVEAAYASAAEgI0vPD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

However I do most of my money management in Fidelity and would like to keep 529 there as well. I can open a 529 there but it doesn't call out the MI state sponsored plan. If I invest there can I still get the MI tax credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can deduct from your state taxes a contribution to a 529 plan it will be on Schedule 1 of the Michigan state tax form. [From the instructions](https://www.michigan.gov/-/media/Project/Websites/taxes/2022RM/IIT/Book_1040_Instructions_Only.pdf?rev=a485e68cd41544d89165f4327221cde9)

> Line 17:
> Michigan 529 Contributions (MESP, MAP, MiABLE). There are
> many 529 savings/investment programs nationwide, but Michigan allows a
> tax deduction for contributions only to the Michigan Education Saving
> Program (MESP), MI 529 Advisor Plan (MAP), and Michigan Achieving a
> Better Life Experience Program (MiABLE). Deduct, to the extent not
> deducted in determining AGI, the total contributions made to the plan
> less qualified withdrawals and rollovers (net) made in the tax year by
> the taxpayer. Determine the net for each Michigan 529 account
> separately. The total deductions on line 17 may not exceed $10,000 for
> a single return or $20,000 for a joint return, and are subject to the
> following additional restrictions:
>
> - MESP and MAP accounts combined:
>   may not exceed $5,000 for a single return or $10,000 for a joint
>   return.
> - MiABLE accounts: may not exceed $5,000 for a single
>   return or $10,000 for a joint return. Line 18: Michigan Education Tr

So you have to contribute to the Michigan programs to deduct the contribution from your state taxes.